# Can a static method always be converted to an instance method?

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, static-methods, instance-methods

If we can make sure the instance is the singleton, then static method can be always converted to instance method? Is that right?

Comment: Using static vs instance methods is a question of design, why would one convert static methods to instance methods if there are reasons to have it static?

Comment: If the instance is a singleton, why are you bothering? A static class (and static methods) are effectively an implementation of the singleton pattern.

Comment: There might be some performance issues if you have to instance a very complex class only to call a method (that should be static) that does absolutely not rely on any state information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course a method marked as `static` can be converted to an instance method. Methods marked as `static` have to be methods that don't use any state information particular to an instance (unless the instance is passed in as a parameter). They can be rewritten the as instance methods and still not rely on state information particular to an instance (or use `this` instead).

Comment: Except of the GetInstance()-method in a singleton class ;)

Comment: @Matten: Nope, that can be rewritten as an instance method too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it of course, but you may break existing code that is calling the static method.  Especially if the method is publicly visible.